# Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении

Tags: запятые

В предложении «Она добрая и у нее красивые волосы» нужна запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Она добрая,  и **у нее** красивые волосы.*

**Пояснение**

Запятая ставится в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП), нет общего элемента.
Дополнение "у нее" относится только ко второму предложению.

Сравнить (предложения с общим дополнением, которое можно **подставить**, тогда **нет запятой**:

Крылья У ГУСЯ были растопырены и клюв (у гуся) раскрыт.

Чужды ВАМ страсти и чужды (вам) страдания.

Взгляд ЕГО был умным   и в голосе (его) звучала сила.

Губы КАТИ не улыбались и глаза (Кати) выражали недоумение.